# How to summerize by column(s) and value with R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In R I have a dataframe with an ID column, multiple columns with a categorical value ('AA', 'AB', 'BB') and 1 column with a numerical value. It looks like this:

| SUBJID | SNP1 | SNP2 | Concentration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'AA' | 'BB' | 20 |
| 2 | 'AA' | 'AA' | 8 |
| 3 | 'BB' | 'BB' | 19 |
| 4 | 'AB' | 'AB' | 30 |

Needed is the mean 'concentration' for each value per column. Can this be done with dplyr in the current dataframe or should I first transform the dataframe to a different shape for example?

I know how to get the mean value for 1 specific column: `df %>% group_by(SNP1) %>% summarise(n=n(), Mean = mean))`. This doesn't help me to get the mean concentration per value within a column **for multiple columns.**

Desired output:

| Group | Mean concentration |
| --- | --- |
| SNP1 'AA' | 20.5 |
| SNP1 'AB' | 22.5 |
| SNP1 'BB' | 19.8 |
| SNP2 'AA' | 20.9 |
| SNP2 'AB' | 18.9 |
| SNP2 'BB' | 15.1 |

Has to be done for up to 13 columns (SNPs).

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: For each column and for each value the mean concentration, Thus for multipe columns the mean for AA, AB and BB. Not just for 1 column as in the dplyr example above.

Comment: please calculate the desired output in respect of sample given above and include that in question too.  It is not clear otherwise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367579/dplyr-group-by-in-a-for-loop-r

Comment: Does something like: 
`df %>% mutate(across(SNP1:SNP2, ~group_by(.)%>%mean(Concentration))` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? The 'trick' here is to `pivot_longer`:

```
libary(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = SNP1:SNP2, names_to = 'col') %>%
  group_by(value, col) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Concentration))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   value [3]
  value col    Mean
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 AA    SNP1   342.
2 AA    SNP2   414.
3 AB    SNP1    10 
4 AB    SNP2    27 
5 BB    SNP1    44 
6 BB    SNP2   200
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to have the `Group`labels as in your desired output, just add a new column:

```
mutate(Group = paste0(col, "_", value))
```

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  SNP1 = c("AA", "AB", "AA", "AA", "BB"),
  SNP2 = c("BB", "AB", "AA", "AA", "AB"),
  Concentration = c(200,10,50,777,44)
)
```