# How can I generate a column that reflects the grouping variable name within a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to be able create a list of variables, and then perform a count of a target variable for each level of each variable in the list.  For clear presentation of the results, I'd like my end result to take the form of four columns: Variable, Level, Result, and Count.

Consider this  partially-there example, borrowing heavily from Brad Cannel's answer at [dplyr- group by in a for loop r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367579/dplyr-group-by-in-a-for-loop-r):

```
df <- tibble(
  var1 = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)),
  var2 = c(rep("c", 3), rep("d", 7)),
  var3 = rnorm(10),
  result=c("good","bad","good","bad","good","bad","good","bad","good","bad")
)

groups <- c(quo(var1), quo(var2))  # Create a quoture

results<-list()

for (i in seq_along(groups)) {
  results[[i]]<-df %>% 
  group_by(!!groups[[i]]) %>% # Unquote with !!
  count(result)
}

all_results<-bind_rows(results)
```

[image]

At this point, the column `n` has the counts that I'd like.  Rather than having columns *named* `var1` and `var2`, I'm hoping to produce a result that looks like:

```
desired_results<-tibble(
variable=c("var1","var1","var1","var1","var2","var2","var2","var2"),
level=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d"),
result=c("bad","good","bad","good","bad","good","bad","good"),
n=c(2,3,3,2,1,2,4,3)
```

)

[image]

I have tried using `mutate` in the loop to produce my result, but can't get the formatting correct:

```
for (i in seq_along(groups)) {
  results[[i]]<-df %>% 
  group_by(!!groups[[i]]) %>% # Unquote with !!
  count(result)%>%
  mutate(level=!!groups[[i]])%>%
  mutate(variable=groups[i])%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  select(variable,level,result,n)
  }
```

I figured out how to "get there" using `pivot_longer`, like so (albeit just needing to rename columsn afterwards):

```
all_results2<-all_results%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(-result,-n))%>%
  filter(!(is.na(value)))
```

I'd really like to know how I could avoid this and just produce a column that houses the variable name right there in the `for` loop, and I'm guessing I'm missing some key bit of syntax. Any help in finding and explaining the solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to pass as `quo`

Comment: Not necessarily.  I could not get the `group_by` working within the `for` loop, but found the example and it worked. If there's another way to do this, even better!

Comment: Also, your desired result is after pivot_longer,  so not clear why you have to first loop

Comment: I'm hoping to have a chunk of code that can look at a list of variables and generate counts with respect to each level of each categorical variable and an outcome variable.  This way, someone else using my code could play with just the variable list, run the code, and get the table with the variables they cared about.  Loop could be the wrong avenue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with `pivot_longer`, without looping, then binding the rows etc

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = var1:var2, names_to = 'variable', 
           values_to ='level') %>% 
    count(variable, level, result)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  variable level result     n
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 var1     a     bad        2
2 var1     a     good       3
3 var1     b     bad        3
4 var1     b     good       2
5 var2     c     bad        1
6 var2     c     good       2
7 var2     d     bad        4
8 var2     d     good       3
```

Comment: another masterful answer, akrun!  This is much easier to look and quicker to type than the original method within my question, rendering my question regarding syntax for referencing the column name unnecessary (though I still wonder anyways).

Comment: @Pake you can pass `groups <- c("var1", "var2")` and `pivot_longer(cols = all_of(groups), ..`

Answer (score 1):

Another option in the larger tidyverse, instead of the `for loop`, would be a call to `purrr::map_dfr`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

groups <- c("var1", "var2")

map_dfr(groups,
        ~ tibble(variable = .x,
                 count(df, level = !!sym(.x), result)))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   variable level result     n
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <int>
#> 1 var1     a     bad        2
#> 2 var1     a     good       3
#> 3 var1     b     bad        3
#> 4 var1     b     good       2
#> 5 var2     c     bad        1
#> 6 var2     c     good       2
#> 7 var2     d     bad        4
#> 8 var2     d     good       3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>